# In the movie Moon (2009 film), why doesn't Sam enhance his chances?

Tags: moon-movie

**spoilers ahead**

In the movie [Moon (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1182345/)…

[image: Moon (2009) Movie Poster]

…Sam Bell discovers…

> …a whole series of clones of himself in the "hidden room".

Since his ultimate goal is to…

> …escape the moon and go to Earth…

…why doesn't he…

> …activate more clones to be able to fight the rescue crew?  After all, he is aware (and scared of) the fact that the rescue crew could stop him from trying to leave the moon. Also, flying to Earth using the rescue ship would certainly be safer than his choice of flying to Earth in that cargo-pod.

So, what's the reason for Sam not to use the (rather logical) option to…

> …activate as many clones as he could so that he could fight off the rescue crew…

… to enhance his chances?

Comment: If you're really concerned about spoiling the fact that Sam is a clone, maybe tagging the question with "clones" isn't the best idea.

Comment: Sam doesn't know how to activate the other Sams, does he? Isn't that just a software protocol carried out by Gerty? At best, to cripple the process he should have destroyed the clones.

Comment: @MeatTrademark What makes you think that Gerty wouldn't help Sam activate more clones? He convinced Gerty to override the usual protocol once, so there's a mighty good chance he could convince Gerty again. Especially, as the movie shows "Help Sam" seems to be the main protocol… because Gerty even helped him by reminding him that rebooting her would wipe her memory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One can imagine that doing this would alert Lunar Industries to the fact that Sam is aware that he is a clone.  So it would be more difficult for him to escape as Lunar Industries would suspect he would and try to cover their tracks.

Moreover, multiple Sam Bells would mean multiple problems.  Each one that has been awaken believes that they are the "real" Sam Bell.

Answer (score 10):

GVIPProgramemer answer makes several good points, I'm going to include some more.

- Each clone that has been awaken believes that they are the "real" Sam Bell:

> *"Hey hello, you are not really you, you are a clone, now help me fight the rescue crew"*

- The psychological state of Sam: Even if he could wake up all the clones without Lunar industries noticing, I don't think he could do that, he realized that

  1. He is not him
  2. He is being used like a simple tool.
  3. He has no family (His family is with the real Sam)
  4. He is going to die within a year
  5. There are more like him, I don't think he could carry on with awaking a clone to tell him the terrible news.

**Awesome movie by the way**